# how to fix following error in ubuntu coming after installing oracle virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, oracle-vm-server

```
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:3
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d
/virtualbox.list:4
```

The meaning of this error is the virtualbox repository is configured multiples times under`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` file. In your case, it is configured 4 times.

to correct the problem, use:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -cs) contrib" |
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
sudo apt update
```